# Please acknowledge message in Oracle forms builder 10g

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am using `Oracle forms builder 10g` and I added a button where I assigned a trigger on button pressed. The `pl/sql code` compiles well, but when I click the button, a `Forms message pop up` saying

> Please acknowledge message

with an `ok button`. When I press ok the code continues to run and I get the desired result.
Note that I have this issue on every trigger I create.
How can I stop this message from popping up? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Raising the `message_level` system parameter  to above `5` would suppress these 
kind of informative messages.

So, you may add below assignment in `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` or `PRE-FORM` trigger for this aim :

```
:system.message_level := 6;
```

***OR alternatively***

without changing `message_level`,

to inspect for the root cause, add `ON-MESSAGE` and `ON-ERROR` trigger(for the `form level`) with a code :

```
/*ON-ERROR*/
declare    
  errcode number        := error_code;
  errtype varchar2(10)  := error_type;
  errtext varchar2(100) := error_text;
begin
   message( errtype | | ' - ' | | to_char(errcode) | | ' : ' | |errtext );
end;

/*ON-MESSAGE*/
declare    
  msgcode number        := message_code;
  msgtype varchar2(10)  := message_type;
  msgtext varchar2(100) := message_text;
begin
 if msgcode in (40400,40401) then
   message('all data successfully saved.');
 else
   message( msgtype | | ' - ' | | to_char(msgcode) | | ' : ' | |msgtext );
 end if;
end;
```

Comment: I prefer modifying message level within a trigger (i.e. exactly where it bothers me), not on a form level. Apart from that, I agree with @Barbaros' suggestion: first set it to a higher level, and then restore it to its original value. Note that you'd want to store its "original" value at the beginning of a trigger, so that you could restore it afterwards.

Comment: I tried this solution and I added :system.message_level := 6; in a WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE trigger, but now I got that message at form load and at button click.

Comment: I tried changing the value to 25 and 0 but still the message pop up appeared on form load, so I think the problem occurs when I assign triggers

Comment: So you'll have to find WHAT causes that message. In order to do that, set the breakpoint (right-click in the left margin of the Editor window) at the beginning of the WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE trigger and run a form in **debug mode** (an icon next to the "normal" run form button). Advance through the code step-by-step until you find it. A blind guess: do you, by any chance, have two consecutive MESSAGE calls somewhere in code?